# Difficulties to understand pointers, dynamic allocation and call to functions behaviour

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, dynamic-allocation

I'm working in C.

I have a simple struct named Entity

```
typedef struct Entity
{
    int x, y;
    int velX, velY;
}Entity;
```

I'm creating a dynamic array of type Entity and size 1. Then I add one element with my `addEntity` function

```
void addEntity(Entity** array, int sizeOfArray)
{
    Entity* temp = malloc((sizeOfArray + 1) * sizeof(Entity));

    memmove(temp, *array, (sizeOfArray)*sizeof(Entity));

    free (*array);
    *array = temp;
}
```

Then I use another function to change the values of the two elements :

```
int main()
{
    Entity* entities = malloc(sizeof(Entity)); // dynamic array of size 1

    addEntity(&entities, 1); // add one element
    changeValue(&entities[0], 10); // change the values of the first two elemebts
    changeValue(&entities[1], 20);

    printf("%d\n", entities[0].x); // print the values
    printf("%d", entities[1].x); 

    free(entities); // free the memory

    return 0;
}

void changeValue(Entity* entity, int nb)
{
    entity->x = nb;
}
```

The result of this is 10 and 20, everything works fine. Now if I use this syntax instead

```
int main()
    {
        Entity* entities = malloc(sizeof(Entity)); // dynamic array of size 1
        addEntityAndSetValues(entities);

        printf("%d\n", entities[0].x); // print the values
        printf("%d", entities[1].x); 

        free(entities); // free the memory

        return 0;
    }

void addEntityAndSetValues(Entity* entities)
{
    addEntity(&entities, 1);
    changeValue(&entities[0], 10);
    changeValue(&entities[1], 20);
}
```

I don't get 10 and 20 but some random numbers. I really don't understand why.

Comment: Note that the `realloc()` function grows an array (so you don't have to write out the copying of the old to the new as you do in `addEntity()`).  Also note that growing an array one element at a time leads to quadratic (slow) behaviour as you're continually moving the data.  Allocate a number of empty array elements and use the extras; when there are none free, double the number allocated.  Other strategies are possible, but one-at-a-time is not good. (If there are only two entities in the array, this doesn't matter, of course. But then you wouldn't need dynamic allocation in the first place.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason is C is pass by value.

When in the second case you pass the pointer - a copy of it is passed to the function. Now when you write `&entities` it is the address of the local variable. And the variables in `main` don't see any change - because you didn't change them. So you get garbage value.

To be more clear

```
void addEntityAndSetValues(Entity* entities)
{
    addEntity(&entities, 1); <--- entities is a local variable.
}
```

Now you add call `addEntity`:

```
void addEntity(Entity** array, int sizeOfArray)
{
    ...
    free (*array);
    *array = temp; <--- assigning to the local variable the address of the allocated chunk.
}
```

Then you call the other function to change it's value - those are alright. But when you return from the function then everything in that local variable is gone.

If you do this - then it would work.

In `main()`

```
addEntityAndSetValues(&entities);
```

In `addEntityAndSetValues()`

```
void addEntityAndSetValues(Entity** entities)
{
    addEntity(entities, 1);
    changeValue(&(*entities)[0], 10);
    changeValue(&(*entities)[1], 20);
}
```

Here it worked because you have passed the the address of the variable in `main()` and then you made changes to that variable - and every change in the value of it reflected.

Comment: I understand, I tried writing `addEntityAndSetValues(&entities);` and replacing the prototype with `Entity** entities`, then I removed every `&` in the function and the result is 10 and a random value.

Comment: @Drakalex.: Check it,,,,

Comment: Oh right, I'm not sure but I think I understand how it works. I 've never seen this syntax before , thanks !